# Decrypt TripleDES "Bad Data"

Tags: c#, encryption, encoding, cryptography

I'm new to encryption/decryption. I'm trying to decrypt an input string that is encrypted and comes out to 44 characters.

This is what I have so far but I keep getting "bad data" when it attempts to execute the "TransformFinalBlock" function.

```
public static String Decrypt(String input)
    {
        try{
            byte[] inputArray = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripleDES = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            tripleDES.KeySize = 128;
            tripleDES.Key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("0123456789ABCDEF");
            tripleDES.IV = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");
            tripleDES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            tripleDES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            ICryptoTransform transform = tripleDES.CreateDecryptor();
            byte[] resultArray = transform.TransformFinalBlock(inputArray, 0, inputArray.Length);
            tripleDES.Clear();

            return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray);
        }
        catch(Exception except){
            Debug.WriteLine(except + "\n\n" + except.StackTrace);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Invalid key, IV and data all would trigger this exception. As symmetric decryption itself will *never* fail, it can only fail on data inside the encrypted blocks (and the encrypted data should be N*blocksize of course). The only data that is verified is the padding. So it will fail on that. Verify that the key and the IV are correct first.

Comment: I was given the KeySize - 128, the Key - "0123456789ABCDEF", the IV - "ABCDEFGH" and the input string. The input string is ABvAsOKcGXqc5uQ4O5Z53isJaH31Pa8+PeddljE4mSU= and is said to TripleDES encrypted and Base64 encoded. I am supposed to decrypt it and output the decrypted string. This is all the information I am given and I do not know much about Cryptography.

Comment: Invalid mode might also trigger this exception :)

Comment: Suggestion: get rid of the try/catch entirely. If there's an exception, then let it propagate instead of returning `null`. Chances are, the caller of the caller will try to do something like `null.Length` and wonder why you did that to him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use an IV, then you should use `CipherMode.CBC`. ECB does not use any IV.

*In addition*, your data is not padded at all, it contains exactly 32 bytes. To test decryption, it is common to try without padding first. That way you can determine by eye which padding is used by looking at the resulting plaintext.

<sub>The plain data is too corny to print here, so I won't.</sub>

Comment: I changed the CipherMode to CBC and removed the padding but it still throws an error in TransformFinalBlock.

Comment: I've tried a few other ways that I have found on the internet but they all do the same thing. I don't have access to the code that was used to encrypt it and I am unsure of what Encoding method I must use for the Key and IV. How would I figure this out/when do you use each?

Comment: Never mind, I got it :). Didn't realize you were saying to actually set the padding to None lol. BTW, you were right. The plain text is pretty corny. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar issue and i fixed it by changing the **PaddingMode** to **None**

My **CipherMode** is **ECB** (Electronic code book).