# tripleDES decryption c#

Tags: c#, encryption, base64, tripledes

I am given a tripleDES encrypted and encoded base 64 string:

ABvAsOKcGXqc5uQ4O5Z53isJaH31Pa8+PeddljE4mSU=

I am also given:

key size = 128;

key = 0123456789ABCDEF

iv = ABCDEFGH

I have written out the following code. I keep on getting an exception thrown at me saying "Bad PKCS7 padding. Invalid length 31" I am losing a byte somewhere I think. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
string base64Encoded = "ABvAsOKcGXqc5uQ4O5Z53isJaH31Pa8+PeddljE4mSU="; // 
string ASCIIkey = "0123456789ABCDEF";
string ASCIIiv = "ABCDEFGH";


TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tDES = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
tDES.KeySize = 128;
tDES.BlockSize = 64;
tDES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
tDES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
tDES.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ASCIIkey);
tDES.IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (ASCIIiv);
byte[] encryptedData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Encoded);
ICryptoTransform transform = tDES.CreateDecryptor();
byte[] plainText = transform.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
string message = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(plainText);
Console.Write (message);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
tDES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
```

and using as a reference `HashAlgorithm.TransformBlock` [sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformblock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (see `PrintHashMultiBlock`)

```
int offset = 0;
while(encryptedData.Length - offset >= size)
    offset += transform.TransformBlock(encryptedData, offset,
                                       encryptedData.Length - offset,
                                       outputBuffer, offset);
```

I was able to get a [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us) phrase

> All Your Base Are Belong To Us!!

---

However a better way is just to change two lines

```
tDES.Padding = PaddingMode.None;  // instead of PaddingMode.PKCS7
tDES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;       // instead of CipherMode.ECB
```

This is suggested by **@MaartenBodewes** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10628540).

So feel free to unaccept the answer, and delete the duplicate :-).

Comment: What do you mean by "and a couple of" @AlexD

Comment: As in `PrintHashMultiBlock` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformblock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (at the bottom).

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not understanding you. So did you copy that whole PrintHashMultiBlock function into the code? @AlexD

Comment: Could you please post the code? Still very confused @AlexD

Comment: @jonjayallday I'm about to post the code. Just give me a bit of time.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much. @AlexD

Comment: @jonjayallday Updated.