# How to catch a decode issue. System.FormatException: 'Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.'

Tags: c#

Here is a hash encoder/decoder with a KEY feature. If I have the wrong key or partial hashed message, upon attempting to decode, I get the Bad Data error. How can I catch this before it breaks?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string hash = "";
        public string Hash { get => hash; set => hash = value; }

        private void btnEncrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            hash = txtKey.Text;
            byte[] data = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtValue1.Text);
            using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider mDS = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                byte[] keys = mDS.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hash));
                using(TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripDes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider() { Key = keys, Mode = CipherMode.ECB, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7 })
                {
                    ICryptoTransform transform = tripDes.CreateEncryptor();
                    byte[] results = transform.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
                    txtValue1.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(results, 0, results.Length);
                }
            }
        }

        private void btnDecrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            hash = txtKey.Text;
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(txtValue1.Text);
            using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider mDS = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                byte[] keys = mDS.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hash));
                using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripDes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider() { Key = keys, Mode = CipherMode.ECB, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7 })
                {
                    ICryptoTransform transform = tripDes.CreateDecryptor();
                    byte[] results = transform.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
                    txtValue1.Text = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(results);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `try` / `catch`?

Comment: But, to answer your question, *"How can I catch this before it breaks?"*.  The answer is in your question.  Use a try/catch (`try { /* your code */ } catch (FormatException ex) { /* code to clean up the problem */ }`

Comment: Just to give you a heads-up "According to draft guidance published by NIST on July 19, 2018, the Triple Data Encryption Algorithm (TDEA or 3DES) is officially being retired. The guidelines propose that, after a period of public consultation, 3DES is deprecated for all new applications and usage is disallowed after 2023" Source: [3DES is Officially Being Retired](https://www.cryptomathic.com/news-events/blog/3des-is-officially-being-retired)

Comment: @Barns thanks. This is a personal project for an escape room sort of game with my kids. Not going to use this commercially lol..

Answer (score 1):

A Base64 string is always a multiple of 4 long. If your text in txtValue1.Text is not a multiple of 4 `if(txtValue1.Text.Length % 4 != 0)` then you won't be able to decode it.

Is it really base64 in that textbox? If so, have you tried appending `=` chars to make it a multiple of 4? (`txtValue.Text  + new string('=', 4 - txtValue.Text.Length % 4)`)

---

Detecting whether TransformFinalBlock would throw a bad data exception would require a considerable amount of code, and isn't worth doing. Just try catch it:

```
try{ 
  byte[] results = transform.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
  txtValue1.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(results, 0, results.Length);
} catch
{
  MessageBox.Show("Key or data is incorrect");
}
```

If you want to catch all exceptions. If you want to catch specific exceptions , catch takes a type:

```
catch(FormatException)
  ...
```

You can have multiple type handlers at the same or parent levels in a hierarchy; specify them in "deepest or peer child to shallowest child" order

If you want to use properties of the exception use a variable name after the type so the block can access the properties of the exception

```
try
  ...
catch(FormatException ex)
  MessageBox "format of ..." + ex.Message
catch(SomeOtherSpecificException ex)
  ...
catch(Exception ex)
  MessageBox "general error of ..." + ex.Message
```

Comment: But, to answer your question, *"How can I catch this before it breaks?"*.  The answer is in your question.  Use a try/catch (`try { /* your code */ } catch (FormatException ex) { /* code to clean up the problem */ }`

Comment: @Flydog57 er.. well, that (to me) is "catching it after it breaks". Catching it before it breaks is detecting a situation that would raise an exception and avoiding it, because exceptions are computationally expensive. I'm not focusing on the word "catch" as being in the "try/catch" sense, more the "detect" sense

Comment: @CaiusJard so ```if(txtValue1.Text.Length % 4 !=0)``` helps if the hash is changed, but any idea how to prevent a break if the key is wrong? My goal is to make it so that if the user doesn't have the correct hashed message and the correct hashed key, then they will be given a "wrong" message.

Comment: Oh, I see.. and also more now of what flydog57 meant when he said he was answering my question (I didn't ask a question) - you, Noel, asked a different question in the title of your SO question than you did in the body. I recommend not to do that; make your question title be a TLDR of your question body. Also have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626126/decrypt-tripledes-bad-data - I think for the "Bad Data" exception you really are going to have to try a decrypt and catch it if it fails per flydog's comment. Avoiding using try/catch is way too complex to be worth doing